# jquery Flot timestamp to week numer

Tags: jquery, timestamp, flot

I use flot and want to display timestamp as week numbers. e.g. 1291590000000 is week 1
the timestamp is already representing the very beginning of a week. How does one do that.

Answer (score 3):

Not entirely sue what you mean.

the [FLOT Documentation](http://flot.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/API.txt) states:

> The time series support in Flot is
>   based on Javascript timestamps, i.e.
>   everywhere a time value is expected or
>   handed over, a Javascript timestamp
>   number is used. This is a number, not
>   a Date object. A Javascript timestamp
>   is the number of milliseconds since
>   January 1, 1970 00:00:00 UTC. This is
>   almost the same as Unix timestamps,
>   except it's in milliseconds, so
>   remember to multiply by 1000!

So, to get the weeks, divide the number by 604800000 (1000*60*60*24*7), and then round. If 1291590000000 is your starting point then substract it your current number (remembering to add 1 if you are treating this as week '1')

```
var start = 1291590000000;
var sometime = 1292590000000;
var weekMillis = 604800000
var weeks = 1 + Math.round((sometime-start)/weekMillis);
alert(weeks );
```

Mocked up at: http://jsfiddle.net/6XDKT/1/